# How to increase only last digit of a serial number string in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, serialization

I'm new to vba and trying to write a barcode scanner algorithm. It works fine right now but I want to keep serial numbers in my exel table and their structure has to be like "A151000". I want with each barcode entered a cell with an inputbox also be assigned to a serial number. for example when a new entry(Barcode) written in column C I want in column B serial numbers last digit increased by 1 and stored in that cell automatically.
Right now I can drag the cell from corner and exel increases the last digit. How can I trigger this with new entries automatically? Thanks in advance.

```
A151000  
A151001  
A151002  
...
```

```
Sub DataInput()

Dim SearchTarget As String
Dim myRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range


Static PrevCell As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim CurCell As Range
Dim a As String
Dim Target As Range
Dim buttonclick As Boolean
V = True

If PrevCell Is Nothing Then
    myRow = Selection.Row
    Set PrevCell = Range("C" & myRow)
End If

Set Rng = Range("C:C,C:C") 'Columns for search defined here

With Rng
    Set FoundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=SearchTarget, _
        After:=PrevCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True)
End With

Dim Eingabezahl As String

Do While Eingabezahl! = ""
    Eingabezahl = InputBox("Last barcode scanned" & "  " & Eingabezahl)
    Range("C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Eingabezahl
    Range("D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Now()
    Range("E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = "VALID"
Loop 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO use the Autofill function and not change your original code you could just add in the autofill in your sub:

```
Dim Eingabezahl As String
Dim rngLastBCell As Range
Do While Eingabezahl = ""
    Eingabezahl = InputBox("Last barcode scanned" & "  " & Eingabezahl)

    Set rngLastBCell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    rngLastBCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(rngLastBCell, rngLastBCell.Offset(1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Eingabezahl
    Range("D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Now()
    Range("E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = "VALID"
Loop
```

Or you could use the following that using the same concept (an autofill) but condenses al of your calls to the worksheet into a single line:

```
Dim Eingabezahl As String
Dim rngLastBCell As Range
Do While Eingabezahl = ""
    Eingabezahl = InputBox("Last barcode scanned" & "  " & Eingabezahl)

    Set rngLastBCell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    rngLastBCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(rngLastBCell, rngLastBCell.Offset(1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    rngLastBCell.Offset(1, 1).Resize(, 3) = Array(Eingabezahl, Now(), "VALID")
Loop
```

Although I would recommend just using appenending the current row to the end of your serial and not making as many calls to the worksheet by using an array:

```
Dim rngB As Range
Dim Eingabezahl As String
Dim SerialBase As String
SerialBase = "A15100"

Do While Eingabezahl = ""
    Eingabezahl = InputBox("Last barcode scanned" & "  " & Eingabezahl)

    Set rngB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    rngB.Resize(, 4).Value = Array(SerialBase & rngB.Row, Eingabezahl, Now(), "VALID")
 Loop
```

Comment: well that solves my problem! thanks a lot for taking time and help!

Comment: Appenending the current row also seems like a great idea to me. It is less complicated I think and does exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot ,I was sick and tired of this issue.. . You are a life saver...